# Using vhost_alias, can I set logs location to the current vhost?

Tags: logging, apache-2.2

I'm not sure my question is clear, but here is a small explication:

I'm using apache mod_vhost_alias, which is great for me to create new domain easily (just create the according domain name folder)
It is configured as is :

```
UseCanonicalName Off
VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%0/htdocs
```

However, I'd like to be able to automatically write log to /var/www/%0/logs

Is there any way to do this with such mod?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell you can't do this out of the box. But you *can* log to a named pipe or directly to a script and have the script recreate the logfiles as you wish:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html#piped

If you need help with the script please post an example of your logfiles.

A non-optimized non-tested example written in shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This assumes the host is mentioned in the first column, replace $1 with the right column if needed.
while read line
  do 
  virtualhost=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`
  echo $line >> /var/www/$virtualhost/log/access_log
done
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for pointing me this option, I tried to do `CustomLog "|/home/user/testlog" combined` It is called correctly, but it seems that it doesn't provide any arguments to the script, how could I retrieve the options to work with? Currently my script is just as follow: `$options = print_r($argv, true); file_puts_content($file);` (php code)

Comment: You can add any arguments inside the quotes, for example: "|/home/user/testlog arg1 arg2 ...". I think you're missing a parameter to file_puts_contents - also I don't think you should use that function in the final implementation, as it opens and closes the destination file each time. This is probably not what you want when logging.

Comment: Hi, I'll think about logging optimization after, well my file_puts_content is correctly signed (not complete indeed in my comments) but works if I can it manually with /home/user/testlog something else foo bar test, result in the correct data dump in my /tmp/log

Comment: You're probably right about optimizing afterward. I added an untested example in shell script in case you find it helpful.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the example, it's working, however I need to find a way to get that line in my php script, I tried both special variable $argv & STDIN but not result, thank you !

Comment: What about `php://stdin`? You may find this helpful: http://www.codeblog.co.uk/2008/03/06/web-platforms/how-to-pipe-logs-from-apache-to-php/

Comment: Yep I succeeded using php://stdin thank you